# torch.multiprocessing.Queue yields no speedup

Tags: python, deep-learning, multiprocessing, shared-memory, torch

My training system consists of a bunch of processes that exchange data in the form of tensors, or list/dictionaries of tensors. Memory sharing via the `torch.multiprocessing` module is a known technique to speedup similar workflows. Yet for some reason it does not help me with my app.

Here's a test script that emulates a system, we create a process and send tensors via a queue:

```
import sys
import time

import torch
from torch.multiprocessing import Process as TorchProcess
from torch.multiprocessing import Queue as TorchQueue


q = TorchQueue()


def torch_shared_mem_process():
    counter = 0

    while True:
        data = q.get()
        counter += 1

        if data is None:
            return

        print('Received data:', len(data), data, counter)


def test_mem_share(share_memory):
    p = TorchProcess(target=torch_shared_mem_process)
    p.start()

    def sample_data():
        return torch.rand([1000, 128, 72, 3], dtype=torch.float)

    start = time.time()

    n = 50
    for i in range(n):
        data = sample_data()

        for data_item in data:
            if share_memory:
                data_item.share_memory_()

        q.put(data)

        print(f'Progress {i}/{n}')

    q.put(None)
    p.join()

    print(f'Finished sending {n} tensor lists!')

    took_seconds = time.time() - start
    return took_seconds


def main():
    no_shared_memory = test_mem_share(share_memory=False)
    with_shared_memory = test_mem_share(share_memory=True)

    print(f'Took {no_shared_memory:.1f} s without shared memory.')
    print(f'Took {with_shared_memory:.1f} s with shared memory.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Since I am using `torch.multiprocessing` I expect version with `share_memory=True` to be faster, but in reality, it is actually marginally slower:

```
Took 10.2 s without shared memory.
Took 11.7 s with shared memory.
```

Did I misunderstand the way `torch.multiprocessing.Queue` works?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `torch.multiprocessing.Queue` already moves tensors to shared memory when transporting them, so `data_item.share_memory_()` shouldn't speed things up any further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this issue? I modified your code a little and there is nothing change (sharing time) when switching between torch.multiprocessing and multiprocessing

```
import sys
import time

import torch
from torch.multiprocessing import Process
from torch.multiprocessing import Queue

# from multiprocessing import Process
# from multiprocessing import Queue

def torch_shared_mem_process(q):
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if data is None:
            return
        print('Received data:', len(data), data)


def test_mem_share():
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=torch_shared_mem_process, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    def sample_data():
        return torch.zeros([100, 3, 1080, 1920], dtype=torch.float)

    data = sample_data()
    start = time.time()
    q.put(data)
    q.put(None)
    p.join()

    print(f'Finished sending tensor!')

    took_seconds = time.time() - start
    return took_seconds

def main():
    shared_memory = test_mem_share()
    print(f'Took {shared_memory:.1f} s with shared memory.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```